# How to start a Server-Sent Event "only once" inside a SharedWorker to push message for any open script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, server-sent-events, shared-worker

I have a [server-sent event (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) implementation that is working with almost no issues. The only issue that I am having is "one user can have many connections to the server". Basically, If a user opens more than one web browser's tab, each tab will create a brand new server-sent event request to the server which cause many requests to run from a single user.

To solve this problem, I would like to run the SSE inside a Javascript's [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker).

This means that I have only one SSE communicating with a SharedWorker. Then, every page/web browser will communication with the SharedWorker. This gives me the advantage of only allowing one SSE per user.

This is how my SSE working currently without any type of worker.

```
$(function(){
    //connect to the server to read messages
    $(window).load(function(){
        startPolling( new EventSource("poll.php") );
    });

    //function to listen for new messages from the server
    function startPolling(evtSource){

        evtSource.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            //handle recieved messages
            processServerData(data);

        }, false);

        evtSource.onerror = function(e) {
            evtSource.close();
        };

    }
});
```

I would like to have the same setup running. However, I would like to run it inside a javascript's SharedWorker to eliminate having more than one SSE per user.

I am struggling to implement the SharedWorker. Here is what I tried so far

I created a file called `worker.js` and added this code to it

```
var ports = [] ;

onconnect = function(event) {

    var port = event.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    port.start();

    var serv = new EventSource(icwsPollingUrl) 
    serv.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        processServerData(data);

    }, false);

}
```

Then on the page where I want to listed to messages I have this code

```
$(function(){

    $(window).load(function(){

        var worker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");         


         worker.port.start();
         worker.port.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
            console.log('Message received from worker');
         }

    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

What am I doing wrong?

How can I correct the implementation?

**EDITED**

Based on the comments below from @Bergi, here is an updated version of my implementation which is still not posting messages to the connectors. I added comments to my code explaining understanding of what is going on with the code.

On a landing page i.e. `index.php` I connect to my SharedWorker like this

```
$(function($){

    //establish connection to the shared worker
    var worker = new SharedWorker("/add-ons/icws/js/worker1.js");
        //listen for a message send from the worker
        worker.port.addEventListener("message",
                function(event) {
                    console.log(event.data);
                }
                , false
        );
        //start the connection to the shared worker
        worker.port.start();

 });
```

This is the code as my `worker1.js` file contains

```
var ports = [] ;

//runs only when a new connection starts
onconnect = function(event) {

    var port = event.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    port.start();

    //implement a channel for a communication between the connecter and the SharedWorker
    port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) { 
            listenForMessage(event, port);
        }
    );
}

//reply to any message sent to the SharedWorker with the same message but add the phrase "SharedWorker Said: " to it
listenForMessage = function (event, port) {
    port.postMessage("SharedWorker Said: " + event.data);

}

//runs every time and post the message to all the connected ports
function readNewMessages(){
    var serv = new EventSource(icwsPollingUrl) 
        serv.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(e) {
        var queue = JSON.parse(e.data);

        notifyAllPorts(queue);

    }, false);
}

//check all open ports and post a message to each
function notifyAllPorts(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
        ports[i].postMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Here is one more version of my `worker1.js`

```
var ports = [] ;

//runs only when a new connection starts
onconnect = function(event) {

    var port = event.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    port.start();

    //implement a channel for a communication between the connecter and the SharedWorker
    port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) { 
            listenForMessage(event, port);
        }
    );
}

//reply to any message sent to the SharedWorker with the same message but add the phrase "SharedWorker Said: " to it
listenForMessage = function (event, port) {
    port.postMessage("SharedWorker Said: " + event.data);

}

readNewMessages();


//runs every time and post the message to all the connected ports
function readNewMessages(){
    console.log('Start Reading...');
    var serv = new EventSource(icwsPollingUrl);
        serv.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(e) {
        var queue = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('Message Received');
        console.log(queue);

        notifyAllPorts(queue);

    }, false);
}

//check all open ports and post a message to each
function notifyAllPorts(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
        ports[i].postMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really wouldn't call this `…Polling` - SSE are a *push* technology :-)

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? What does not work, are there any errors? What is `processServerData`? Do you ever post a message from the worker to the conncted page(s)?

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't create a `new EventSource(icwsPollingUrl)` in the `onconnect` handler of your worker, this just does create one eventsource per connecting web page again.

Comment: @Bergi where would I create the connection then? The `processServerData` functions reads the message send by SSE and it process it "display different messages to the screen"  I am trying to implement a push technology where one message is read and pushed to any open browser

Comment: `onconnect` is not called when your worker does connect to your push service, but when a web page does connect to your worker. You will want to create the `new EventSource` only once right in (the startup of) the worker itself.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the code based on your comments. However, no messages are being sent to the ports aka scripts. I updated my question with the new implementation to make sure you have the latest code. Please advise.

Comment: Which message do you expect to be sent from where? Neither do you call `readNewMessages()` in the initialisation of your worker, nor do your pages send any events that the worker would then echo.

Comment: @Bergi the function `readNewMessages()` should start connection to the php script to get net messages. Then it should take each message, convert it from json to object and finally posts that object to the scrips. I thought I am suppose to call this function outside the `onconnect` method so it is not executed every-time a script connects to the SharedWorker.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to do exactly that. But I don't see that call to the function in the code you posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88391/discussion-between-mike-a-and-bergi).

Answer (score 3):

maybe is late but you can create a EventSource singleton in the worker like this:

```
let ports = [];
var EventSourceSingleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new EventSource('your path');
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

onconnect = function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    var notifyAll = function(message){
        ports.forEach(port => port.postMessage(message));
    }

    var makeConnection = function (){
        var source = EventSourceSingleton.getInstance();

        source.onopen = function (e){
            var message = "Connection open"
            port.postMessage(message);
        }
        source.onerror = function(e){
            var message ="Ups you have an error";
            port.postMessage(message);
        }
        source.onmessage = function(e){
            // var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
            notifyAll(e.data);
        }
    }

    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        makeConnection();
    }
    port.start();
  }
```

And you can call it from outside like this.

```
            var shWorker = new SharedWorker('woker.js');

            shWorker.port.onmessage = function (e) {
                console.log('Message received from worker');
                setmsj(e.data);
            }
            //Dummy message - For initialize
            shWorker.port.postMessage(true);
```

Have fun debuggin this on // chrome://inspect/#workers.

Comment: So IIUC the reason you need a singleton is because else each call to `new SharedWorker("worker.js")` would create new instance... but I don't understand why they'd choose to have it behave like that instead of running it once and then just return a handle to the worker object or something.